# Create object at runtime for Table per hierarchy addition

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-4

I have a base class and there are derived classes. The base class is mapped to a table using EF4 TPH(Table-per-hierarchy). In my application, the user can select one of the many derived classes and then I need to save them with the "Discriminator" column correctly populated.

On the UI the user enters Id & Name only (base class properties) and hence I am storing user entries in a list of base class objects. Since I get to know which derived type the user has selected at run time, I am not sure how to do this.

So far I've tried using Convert.ChangeType on the base objects to get the derived class object and then doing an Add to the entity. But it fails with "Object must implement IConvertible."

Not sure what else can I do. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var derivedEntity = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourDerivedType));` then attach it.

Or better still, let entity framework do it for you:

```
var entity = Context.Set<TEntity>().Create();
```

Where `Context` is your `DbContext`.

Comment: Ok, I did the Activator.CreateInstance() and it worked. {I swear I'd tried it before putting the question and it did not. Well!}.
But I do not understand the Context.Set<TEntity>().Create(). How will that work? Any examples on how that would be called? Will TEntity be a derived type?
Thanks.

Comment: @rjv_rnjn. The second requires that you can get to the compiled type at runtime. An example of this would be: `BaseType entity = condition ? Context.Set<DerivedA>().Create() : Context.Set<DerivedB>();`.

Comment: @rjv_rnjn. I that that is particular to Code first too. Though there will be a similar method for DB first. Similar is: `Context.DerivedASet.Create...`

Answer (score 0):

You may store the objects as a list of base class objects, however, you should instantiate the derived class objects. If you don't do it in the first place, do you really need different classes?

Comment: My code can not instantiate the derived class of objects when the user is making the selection (because I do not know at compile time what they will select). And I do not want to make separate list of objects for each type they can select. I need the derived classes because they have different behavior with the same property values.
And no idea who/why the down vote?